# Object detection increase font size

Tags: fonts, object-detection

I have an image being detected with bounding boxes but the font size too small for me. I have tried doing other ways like changing the arial.ttf, 24 line but no change whatsoever. Is there any other way to change the font size?

try:
font = ImageFont.truetype('/windows/fonts/arial.ttf', 48)
except IOError:
font = ImageFont.load_default()

Answer (score 0):

Check your path of `visualization_utils`

```
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
print(vis_util)
```

Edit font size in `vis_util` file from that path
My path at `C:Python/lib/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py`